# Gnuplot Bar Chart with Defined Upper Error and Lower Error - Horizontally Shifted?

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, errorbar

I have data that is of the format:

```
name y err_lower err_higher
```

That is, I have specific values that I want to be the top of the error bar and the bottom of the error bar, for my two series y1 and y2.

My script is:

```
fontsize = 12
set term postscript enhanced eps fontsize size 20,4
set output "results.eps"
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set style histogram errorbars
set style data histogram
set xtics rotate by -45 
set grid ytics
set ylabel "EMD"
set yrange [0:4] 

plot 'results.tsv' using 2:3:4:xticlabels(1)
```

This results in a chart where the error bars are horizontally shifted, out of sync with the bar that the error is meant for. A snippet of the produced graph:

[image]

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here? This problem also occurs for clustered bar charts, which is what I'm actually trying to create.

If it matters, I have quite a lot of lines in the datafile (528) so the chart is quite horizontally long.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37200619/2604213

Comment: Feel pretty stupid now. Completely forgot about the header in my data file despite knowing that it needs to be handled for gnuplot to work properly. This solved my problem, thanks very much.